# Using \dot{x} produces a bar below the letter

Tags: symbols

I'm trying to put a dot above some letters (as in derivatives wrt time), and I know that this is achieved by `\dot{x}`, `\ddot{x}`, etc. In one of my texts it worked neatly, and in the one I'm writing now it produces a bar under the letters. I tried comparing the preambles, but I didn't find anything that different.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{gfsartemisia-euler}

\begin{document}
\[  \dot{a}, \quad \dot{b}, \quad \dot{c} \]
\end{document}
```

Gives:

[image]

I would say that there's some incompatibilty with the `gfsartemisia` font, but the other text I said it worked also uses that font. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on an answer to a similar question ([Unable to show a derivative with `\dot` in gfsartemisia-euler font (inside TikZ figure)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79028/unable-to-show-a-derivative-with-dot-in-gfsartemisia-euler-font-inside-tikz)):

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{gfsartemisia-euler}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareMathAccent{\dot}{\mathalpha}{artemisiaeulernumbers}{"01}


\begin{document}
\[  \dot{a}, \quad \dot{b}, \quad \dot{c} \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works, thanks. Also thanks for pointing the similar question too.